# Set a string conditionally

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements

I don't know exactly how to explain my problem but I'll do what I can.

I have two strings: `string1`, `string2`
Now I want to update either one of them giving the condition an integer `condInt` needs to be  -1.

I have this code and I'd like to reduce it..

```
If condInt <> -1 Then
            If (optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue) Then
                string1 = MainString.Substring(whereSelector + 6)
            Else
                string1 = MainString.Substring(whereSelector + 6, optimizationSelector - (whereSelector + 6))
            End If
        Else
            If optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue Then
                string2 = MainString.Substring(fromSelector + 5)
            Else
                string2 = MainString.Substring(fromSelector + 5, optimizationSelector - (fromSelector + 5))
            End If
        End If
```

Now I replace some code by using: `Dim startValueToUse = IIf(whereSelector <> -1, whereSelector + 6, fromSelector + 5)`

That results in:

```
Dim startValueToUse = IIf(whereSelector <> -1, whereSelector + 6, fromSelector + 5)
If condInt <> -1 Then
            If (optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue) Then
                string1 = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse )
            Else
                string1 = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse , optimizationSelector - (startValueToUse ))
            End If
        Else
            If optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue Then
                string2 = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse )
            Else
                string2 = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse , optimizationSelector - (startValueToUse))
            End If
        End If
```

I thought maybe I could remove the if by replacing string1 & string2 by using `Iif(condInt <> -1, string1, string2)`. So it would result in this:

```
    Dim startValueToUse = IIf(whereSelector <> -1, whereSelector + 6, fromSelector + 5)
                If (optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue) Then
                    Iif(condInt <> -1, string1, string2) =
MainString.Substring(startValueToUse )
                Else
                    Iif(condInt <> -1, string1, string2) =
MainString.Substring(startValueToUse , optimizationSelector - (startValueToUse ))
                End If
```

But the result of that is an error, it's not possible.. What can I do to make something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use the IIF function at the left side of the equals operator.
Also, I suggest to drop the IIF function and use the IF ternary operator syntax that short circuit the evaluation of your code

```
    If condInt <> -1 Then
        string1 = If(optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue, _
                     MainString.SubString(whereSelector + 6), _
                     MainString.Substring(whereSelector + 6, optimizationSelector - (whereSelector + 6)))
    Else
        string2 = If(optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue, _
                  MainString.Substring(fromSelector + 5), _
                  MainString.Substring(fromSelector + 5, optimizationSelector - (fromSelector + 5)))
    End If
```

Your problem is the fact that you want to initialize two different string variables depending on the condition of the variable `condInt` so you need two different cases

Comment: I was used to programming with C# which has a totally different ternary operator. I thought Iif was the Vb-like ternary operator. I'll be using If from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Dim startValueToUse = If(whereSelector <> -1, whereSelector + 6, fromSelector + 5)
Dim result = If(optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue, MainString.Substring(startValueToUse), MainString.Substring(startValueToUse, optimizationSelector - startValueToUse))
```

It computes the result in the variable result, dropping string1 and string2. Do you really need to have both ?

Comment: I need both strings seperated, because those eventually result in two different objects.

Comment: Since you don't use string1 & string2 at the same time (whereSelector can't be = -1 and <> -1), I would go for only one variable. You still can instantiate 2 differents objects depending on the value of the variable result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use iif like that. If your strings are really names string1 and string2 then you could use an array instead.

```
If condInt <> -1 Then
    index = 1
Else
    index = 2
End If


If (optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue) Then
    stringValue(index) = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse )
Else
    stringValue(index) = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse , optimizationSelector - (startValueToUse ))
End If
```

If not, you can put the value in a temporary place

```
If (optimizationSelector = Integer.MaxValue) Then
    tempString = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse )
Else
    tempString = MainString.Substring(startValueToUse , optimizationSelector - (startValueToUse ))
End If

If condInt <> -1 Then
    string1 = TempString
Else
    string2 = tempString
End If
```